# Setup cron job on Wampserver on Windows 10

Tags: php, cron, scheduled-tasks, wampserver, recurring-billing

I have bought a script from codecanyon which bills clients. In this script there is a feature called recurring bills which generates bill every month/week.

But, in order to use recurring feature, I need to setup Cron Jobs. I have read a lot of articles about cron jobs on Windows, tried a lot, but nothing seems to work.

Things I have done:

1. I am using wampserver, So enabled php_curl
2. In the documentation of the script it says: **I need to run this: "/usr/bin/curl --silent --compressed http://yoursite/cronjob/index"** every 12 hours."

   So in order to do that, I started googling and I came across a link  `http://www.web-site-scripts.com/knowledge-base/article/AA-00487/0/Setup-Cron-job-on-Windows-7-Vista-2008.html`.
3. I have put path of php in environment variables.

Comment: What is the name of the software? Need to see the documentation.

Comment: This is the link to the software: https://codecanyon.net/item/wilylab-invoice-recurring-multiple-company-invoice

Comment: why not try to used schedule task on windows? (Control Panel -> Scheduled Tasks -> Add Scheduled Task).

Comment: In you page url return: `404 - Nothing to see here`

Comment: @Shudmeyer - I can try that but how do I add the url as mentioned in the question?

Comment: @Avishake https://codecanyon.net/item/wilylab-invoice-recurring-multiple-company-invoice/9689396 Sorry

Comment: @TabassumAhmed, there is an optional value "Add arguments" put the link there

Comment: @Shudmeyer Should I put the entire link there: 
Eg: ""/usr/bin/curl --silent --compressed http://yoursite/cronjob/index""
How do I replace /usr/bin/curl ? I mean What should be the lcoation of curl?

Comment: The link only for the Add arguments. then on Program/Script put the service to run the link. (e.g. location/path of curl)